# Configure cURL with shared build not working

Tags: curl, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile cURL for an embedded system that uses an ARM11 processor; for use with HTTP only. However, I need the build to be shared.

*Note: I'm using the gcc-arm compiler.*
See my config options below:

```
    ./configure --prefix=${ROOTDIR}/build \
        --target=${CROSS_COMPILE} \
        --host=${CROSS_COMPILE} \
        --build=i386-pc-linux-gnu \
        --without-ssl \
        --without-zlib \
        --disable-cookies \
        --disable-verbose \
        --disable-versioned-symbols \
        --disable-static --enable-shared \
        --disable-ftps --disable-gopher \
        --disable-imap --disable-imaps \
        --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps \
        --disable-pop3 --disable-pop3s \
        --disable-rtmp --disable-rtsp \
        --disable-dict --disable-file \
        --disable-ftp --disable-sftp \
        --disable-smb --disable-smbs \
        --disable-smtp --disable-smtps \
        --disable-telnet --disable-tftp
```

This however produces the following build configuration:
**Build libcurl:    Shared=no, Static=yes**
This is the complete opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a shared library without OS knowledge.
What are you running on this embedded system?
If you are running linux, you should use some gcc-*linux*-arm compiler (e.g. arm-linux-gnueabi).

Also see this - [Libtool claims it does not support shared libraries during cross compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368627/libtool-claims-it-does-not-support-shared-libraries-during-cross-compilation)

Comment: Hi there that is the compiler that I'm using. The embedded OS is not Linux it's a proprietary OS from Verifone. Also, once the code is compiled with the correct endianess, for the correct processor, etc. it would work. At this point I don't care about creating the library again. If I could just generate the object files I'll simply link to those for testing. Thanks.